# Google Apps Script Regular Expression to get the last name of a person

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I am trying to write a regex to get the last name of a person.

```
var name = "My Name";
var regExp = new RegExp("\s[a-z]||[A-Z]*");
var lastName =  regExp(name); 
Logger.log(lastName);
```

If I understand correctly `\s` should find the white space between `My` and `Name`, `[a-z]||[A-Z]` would get the next letter, then `*` would get the rest. I would appreciate a tip if anyone could help out.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
var name = "John Smith";
var regExp = new RegExp("(?:\\s)([a-z]+)", "gi"); // "i" is for case insensitive
var lastName = regExp.exec(name)[1];
Logger.log(lastName); // Smith
```

But, from your requirements, it is simpler to just use `.split()`:

```
var name = "John Smith";
var lastName = name.split(" ")[1];
Logger.log(lastName); // Smith
```

Or `.substring()` (useful if there are more than one "last names"):

```
var name = "John Smith Smith";
var lastName = name.substring(name.indexOf(" ")+1, name.length); 
Logger.log(lastName); // Smith Smith
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives. Very helpful. Just a quick question about the regex. If I understand it right: 
() brackets mean evaluate this first
?: means don't record into the regex
\s is white space
What is the purpose of the extra "\" ?

Comment: The `()` in `([a-z]+)` is actually for [grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). It allows us to use that matched part again later. `(?:)` (the `()` are mandatory here) means the opposite, do not include this group, thus just use the `()` as regular `()`, useful for applying operators to multiple expressions (like in `(\s\w)+`, `(\s\w)` would be a group. In `(?:\s\w)+` it is not.). The extra `\ `is necessary because your regex was declared using the `RegExp` constructor, and it gets a string as parameter. Thus the need for escaping `\ `as `\\ `. Let me know if it is clear!