# Removing tabs and newlines with regular expressions issue

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

Regex: remove TAB `\t` tab `var regex = /\s[A-Za-z]+/g` do not work

```
selectFirstEmptyRow function () {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl ("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/---ID-----edit#gid=395019283");
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date() ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "d" + "- 0" + "M" + "-" + "y");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(date);
  var regex = /[^0-9]*/g; // extract the string before digital channel
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getText()
  var result = RegExp.exec(doc);
 // * Extract white \ s match any white space character [\ r \ n \ t \ f]
  var regex = /\s[A-Za-z]+/g; // extract the spaces in front of and behind "Name Surname"
  RegExp.exec var result = (result);
  sheet.setActiveSelection(sheet getRange ("B" + getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow())).setValue(result);
   Logger.log(result.getText);
```

I can not remove a tab `\t` and newlines `\n` with the syntax

```
var regex = /\s[A-Za-z]+/g;
```

There remains a line preceding the `string "Name Surname"` when I insert it into the Spreadsheet.
  After analysis it appears that the concerns are the tabs `\t`, it is not deleted.

I try to extract from a `"text document"` a string (which is always at the top of the document until the first numerical chain) and put in a "spreadsheet document 'Spreadsheet at the site of the first box vacuum column `"B"`.

The handling of this string in the same `"text document"` did not cause me any problem for the update of age with the syntax

```
 var regex = /[^0-9]*/g; // extract the string before a digit
```

The string from the document:

```
var str = '\n\n\n\Surname NAME\n34 Years\n\n......... .. "
```

Here is the complete script:

///  var result = result.replace(/^[\r\n]+|.|[\r\n]+$/g, "");// extrait les espaces devant et derriere Nom Prenom  GAS D'ONT WORK

```
 /////    Facturer  Acte      ////

     function FacturerActe() {

      var regexp = /[^0-9]*/g ;// extrait la chaine de caractère avant la chaine numérique
      var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getText();
      var result = regexp.exec(doc);
      var PrenomNom = new RegExp(result,"gm"); 
      Logger.log(PrenomNom.getText);

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19rWt8JEGbYM29-W4tI2gj6peXR3hjvj51FxDFt2gFkU/edit#gid=395019283");
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone() , "d"+"-"+"mm"+"-"+"y");
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(date);
      ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);

      var cell = sheet.getRange("A40");
      cell.setNote("Aujourd'hui est un nouveau jour ! Nous sommes le :"+date);

      selectFirstEmptyRow(); // Place le curseur sur la premiere ligne Vide de la Colonne "B"
    }

     //* Placez le curseur de l'utilisateur actuel dans la première cellule de la première ligne vide.
     //*
    function selectFirstEmptyRow()  { 

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19rWt8JEGbYM29-W4tI2gj6peXR3hjvj51FxDFt2gFkU/edit#gid=395019283");
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone() , "d"+"-"+"mm"+"-"+"y");
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(date);
      var regexp = /[^0-9]*/g ;// extrait la chaine de caractère avant la chaine numérique

      var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getText();
      var result = regexp.exec(doc);
      var regexp = /\s[A-Z a-z]+/g ;// extrait les espaces devant et derriere Nom Prenom
    //* Extrait les blancs

      var result = regexp.exec(result);

    ///  var result = result.replace(/^[\r\n]+|\.|[\r\n]+$/g, "");// extrait les espaces devant et derriere Nom Prenom  GAS D'ONT WORK

      sheet . setActiveSelection (sheet.getRange("B" + getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow())).setValue(result);
       Logger.log(result.getText);
    }

    /**
     * " Trouve la première ligne vide la Colonne "B" " de checker de Mogsdad.
     */ 
    function getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow ()  { 

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19rWt8JEGbYM29-W4tI2gj6peXR3hjvj51FxDFt2gFkU/edit#gid=395019283");
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "d"+"-"+"mm"+"-"+"y");
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(date);
      var range = sheet.getDataRange(); 
      var values = range.getValues(); 
      var row =  1 ; 
      for  (var row = 1; row < values.length; row ++)  { 
        if  (!values[ row ].join(""))  break ; 
      } 

      return  (row + 1); 

    }

     /////   Fin   Facturer  Acte      ////
```

Comment: I don't see any instance created for the regex variable as in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573598/google-apps-script-regular-expression-to-get-the-last-name-of-a-person. Try changing it and see if that works.

Comment: Also your regex is wrong. az should be a-z etc

Comment: Zig ! Error because of the auto translate on stackoverflow.com .The Regex is : var regexp = /\s[A-Z a-z]+/g ;  but this Other Regex work better
   var regexp = /[^a-z\s-]+[A-Z\s-]+/g;

Answer (score 1):

As per [Using regular expressions to search for data in your spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754?p=spreadsheets_find_replace&rd=2), you can match any newline and tab using `[\t\r\n]` pattern. Since you have more than one at a stretch, you should add a quantificator `+`. Also, since you are looking to capture 2 lines, you should add the `[\t\r\n]+` to the pattern, too.

This will let you capture the 2 lines with Name and Age in between the newlines:

```
[\r\n\t]+(.+[\r\n\t]+.+)[\t\r\n]+
```

And you can later remove the newline characters:

```
var result = str.replace(/[\r\n\t]+(.+[\r\n\t]+.+)[\t\r\n]+/, '$1');
```

Here is what it looks like on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nC7tV0/3).

```js
alert("'" + "\n\t\n\nNew line\n\t\nSecond 34 line\n\t\n....".replace(/[\r\n\t]+(.+[\r\n\t]+.+)[\t\r\n]+/, '$1') + "'")
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup . Fantastique

Comment: Pas du tout. Veuillez approuver la réponse, s'il vous plaît.