# Google Sheets 'Exception: Range not found' error for URL formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this formula that extracts the link from a word with hyperlink. Now when I'm trying to move it to another spreadsheet and run it I get an 'Exception: Range not found' error. I was reading this might be cuz I need a 'getRangeList' insted of getRange, but it doesn't work this way either. Now I get the 'Exception: The parameters (number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRangeList.'
Here's the code I'm using:

```
function URL(refrence) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var a1 = formula.replace("=url(","");
  a1 = a1.replace(")","");
  var url = sheet.getRange(a1).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
  return url
}
```

Comment: The variable a1 may not have the correct range value. You have a sample value for the formula cell ?

Comment: `a1` is technically not a range, but a _replaced_ value from formula, which is still not a valid range. Try using `getActiveRange()` instead of  `getRange(a1)`.

Comment: @RodrigoBiffi if I change just that I get the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLinkUrl' of null (line 6)."

Answer (score 2):

### FINDINGS

- The part `getRange(a1)` is incorrect as the variable `a1` contains an invalid Sheet range.

### SUGGESTION

If your main goal is to easily extract the URL from a cell with hyperlink like `=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/","Google")` you may use these tweaked scripts below:

*These scripts were derived from the answers of these posts [How to extract URL from Link in Google Sheets using a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59348002)  & [Google Apps Script Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17573904)*

> **This version of the script will only show the `url` value from the Apps Script editor's log results:**

```
function URL() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = sheet.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var regExp = new RegExp("\"(.*)\",\"", "gm");
  var url = regExp.exec(formula)[1];
  Logger.log(url)
}
```

**Note:** *Before running, make sure the cell with hyperlink is selected on your sheet (in my case it was on cell `A1`).*

### Sample result on the logs:

[image]

> **This another version will let you to use your script as a custom function `=URL()` on your spreadsheet file:**

```
function URL(refrence) {
  var regExp = new RegExp("\"(.*)\",\"", "gm");
  var url = regExp.exec(refrence)[1]
  return url
}
```

### Sample Result as a custom function:

```
=URL(FORMULATEXT(A1))
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[FORMULATEXT function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365792)